# How to connect to oracle instance on EC2 from sqldeveloper?

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2

I have created ec2 windows instance and created Oracle db there.

I am trying to connect to db on ec2 from sqldeveloper.

But I am getting below error:

> The Network adapter could not establish the connection.

I have changed `listner.ora` file, still I am getting same error.

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the port? Typically firewalls are configured to restrict all access. At least that's what I had to do when I ran the DB on an AWS host (I switched to using RDS but even then I had to have firewall rules in place to allow access)

Comment: i am using amazon workspace where sqldeveloper is installed....and EC2 and workspace are in same vpc....actually we tried to connect using linux oracle ec2 instance and we are able to connect to that...but for windows ec2 instance we are facing problem

Comment: This can help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273138/how-to-solve-vendor-code-17002-when-connecting-to-a-remote-oracle-database/